# ¿Como mostrar un mensaje de vació en un RecyclerView?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Quisiera mostrar un mensaje de vacío cuando el RecyclerView, no tenga ningún ítem o también seria genial cual es el método para saber si un RecyclerView esta vacío.

Comment: Hola, no estas preguntando correctamente , en esta comunidad, es normal publicar el código del intento de resolver el problema. Pues en general si los demás ven que no lo intentastes hacer es difícil que te ayuden.El método public int getCount() { es el que te cuenta cuantos items tiene el recyclerView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normalmente para saber si un RecyclerView esta vacío lo haces a través del adaptador, ya que este es el que tiene los "View" por medio del ViewHolder.

Si quieres mostrar un mensaje cuando tu RecyclerView este vacío lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera

```
if(myRecyclerView.getAdapter() != null){
    //De esta manera sabes si tu RecyclerView está vacío
    if(myRecyclerView.getAdapter.getItemCount == 0) {
        //Aquí muestras el mensaje
    }

}
```

Espero que te haya ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

Quisiera compartir la solución que encontré:

> XML

```
oid:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/contenedor_margen"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/contenedor_margen"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.tu-paquete.nombre-app.ListaFragmento">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_lista"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    //Resto margen top -100dp por que lo incluyo en un layout que tiene un toolbar
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sms_lista_vacia"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="-100dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

> Código: **ListaFragmento**

```
public class ListaFragmento extends Fragment{
   private RecyclerView mRecycler;
   private TextView mListaVacia;
   private RecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter;
   //[...]

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmento, container, false);
    mListaVacia = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sms_lista_vacia);
    mRecordatoriosRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.rv_lista);

    //Implementación para la carga de los item [....]

    //Mostrar un mensaje si la lista esta vacía [cuando carga la app]
    int numItems =  mAdapter.getItemCount();
    if(numItems == 0)
        listaVacia();
    else
        listaConDatos();

    //Mostar un mensaje cuando se utiliza los metodos add, remo, set del adaptador RecyclerView
    //Cuenta con vacior metodos @Override utiliza el que je ajuste a tu necesidad 
    mAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {

        @Override
        public void onItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount) { //Solo se invoca cuando se utiliza la función [ejemplo] notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mDatos.size); 
            super.onItemRangeChanged(positionStart, itemCount);

            if(itemCount == 0)
                listaVacia();
            else
                listaConDatos();

        }

    });
    return v;
  }
}

//Cargo esta función si la lista no contiene datos
public void listaVacia(){

  String sms = "No hay datos para mostrar! :(";

  mListaVacia.setText(sms);
  mListaVacia.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  mRecycler.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}
//Cargo esta función si la lista contiene datos
public void listaConDatos(){
  mListaVacia.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  mRecycler.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```