# Detectar si un RecyclerView esta vacío

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Buen día, parece un duplicado de esta pregunta:

[¿Como mostrar un mensaje de vació en un RecyclerView?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/101882/114296)

Pero realmente no me funciona a pesar de que utilizo el mismo código, he probado otros distintos y tampoco funcionan.

Resulta que necesito validar cuando mi **recycler** este vacío y así mostrar un mensaje al usuario.
Estoy usando **MySQL** y **PHP** para obtener los datos en en **recycler** para las peticiones utilizo la librería **volley** este es el código que tengo por el momento:

Declaro mi Vista de reciclaje, mi adaptador e instancio mi modelo:

```
RecyclerView rvProductos;
AdapProdReport adaptador;
List<DetReporte> listaProdReport;
```

Luego los inizializo:

```
rvProductos = vista.findViewById(R.id.rvProductos);
rvProductos.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

listaProdReport = new ArrayList<>();

adaptador = new AdapProdReport(getContext(), listaProdReport);
rvProductos.setAdapter(adaptador);
```

Y finalmente obtengo los datos de **MySQL** con el siguiente método (Dentro de esta método valido si el **recycler** esta vacío):

```
public void obtenerPedido() {

    String url_det_pedido = "Mi URL";

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,url_det_pedido,

            response -> {

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Detreporte");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        Double totalFila = jsonObject1.getDouble("monto") + jsonObject1.getDouble("monto_iva");
                        gTotal = gTotal + totalFila;

                        totalFinal.setText(String.format("%.2f", gTotal));

                        listaProdReport.add(

                                new DetReporte(

                                        Login.gIdFacDetPedido = jsonObject1.getInt("id_det_prefactura"),
                                        jsonObject1.getString("nombre_producto"),
                                        jsonObject1.getDouble("cantidad_producto"),
                                        jsonObject1.getDouble("precio_venta"),
                                        jsonObject1.getDouble("monto"),
                                        jsonObject1.getDouble("monto_iva")));

                    }

                    adaptador = new AdapProdReport(getContext(), listaProdReport);
                    rvProductos.setAdapter(adaptador);

                    if(rvProductos.getAdapter() != null){

if(rvProductos.getAdapter.getItemCount == 0) {
    //El recycler esta vacio
}

}

            
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                
                }
            }, Throwable::printStackTrace
    );

    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            0,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Y eso seria todo espero me puedan ayudar de antemano muchas gracias!